# <div> won't display in c-section-header

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, lightning-design-system

I am trying to add helptext underneath the header of a page. For some reason, when I add the div with slot="testSlot" in the below code, the div doesn't even render.

Screenshot of what I want it to look like: (I had to change the CSS in Dev Console to get this). For some reason, the helptext under the "Objects" heading is not rendering.
[image]

Code:

```
<!-- Objects and Fields Tab -->
                        <div class="tab-content" if:true={renderObjects}>
                            <c-section-header title={objectSectionTitle} subtitle={objectSectionSubTitle} style="display:inline">
                                <div slot="actions">
                                    <lightning-button
                                        label="Objects"
                                        if:true={showAddObjects}
                                        icon-name="utility:add"
                                        class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                                        variant="brand"
                                        onclick={handleAddObject}>
                                    </lightning-button>
                                    
                                    <lightning-button
                                        label="Go Back"
                                        if:true={hasSelectedObject}
                                        icon-name="utility:back"
                                        class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                                        variant="default"
                                        onclick={handleObjectsGoBack}>
                                    </lightning-button>
                                </div>

                                <div slot="testSlot">
                                    <p style="display: block">Use the + Objects button to specify permissions for Objects - Test2</p>
                                </div>
                                
                            </c-section-header>
```

Comment: Without seeing the source code for c-section-header, we can't help you. This is a custom component in your org. I will say that if a named slot does not exist in the component, then the slotted elements cannot appear. That's how slots work.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize it was a custom component that had a template set. One I found the HTML template I was able to update that and fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I was able to help.